# javascript syntax error in node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

The problem is that when I start the server I get the error listed below.  I'm pretty new to JavaScript, is this due to a difference in JavaScript or Nodejs versions? I also tried changing the var update to have `[]` instead of `{}`, but which gets the server to start, but then it won't update/delete data from our MongoDB. If it helps, the "Recipes" in `Recipes.findOneAndUpdate` is a Mongoose schema.

Here is the function from the server.js:

```
app.post("/updaterecipe", function(req, res) {
var id = req.body.recipeID;
console.log("Updating recipe " + id);
var recipeName = req.body.recipeName;
var categoryID = req.body.categoryID;
var recipeInstructions = req.body.recipeInstructions;
var ingredientIDs = req.body.ingredientIDs;
var options = {new: false};
var update = {recipeName, categoryID, recipeInstructions, ingredientIDs};
console.log(update);
Recipes.findOneAndUpdate({recipeID: id}, update, options, function(err) {
    if (err)
    {
        console.log("Unable to update");
        console.log(err);
    }
});
res.send(update);
});
```

And the error:

```
var update = {recipeName, categoryID, recipeInstructions, ingredientIDs};
                        ^
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
>       at startup (node.j

Comment: what version of node?

Comment: Node version is v0.12.1

Comment: update it, you cant use that syntax in the older node versions, go to 6+

Comment: The update fixed it, thanks! My version was super old.

Comment: Awesome, I'll post it as the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ES6 property shorthand:

```
var update = {recipeName, categoryID, recipeInstructions, ingredientIDs};
```

source: http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand

Simply upgrade to the latest version of node and you should be good to go.

Comment: Note that this will replace OP document in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your JSON. You are trying to create an invalide JSON object.

The following change to **var update** should do the trick.

```
var update = {
        "recipeName": recipeName,
        "categoryID": categoryID,
        "recipeInstructions": recipeInstructions,
        "ingredientIDs": ingredientIDs
     };
```

Comment: while this works, what he's doing is fine in the es6, but its not supported in his version of node

Answer (score 0):

Your update document is not valid in ES5 because as already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365571/3100115), the *Shorthand property names* is new in (ES6), so you need to specify the "key"'s name or upgrade to a Nodejs version that use ES6 . That being said you also need to use the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/set/) update operator because if you fail to use an $-modifier, your query will do a full-document replacement, replacing the matched document with the value of `update`.

```
var update = { 
    "$set": {
        "recipeName": recipeName,
        "categoryID": categoryID,
        "recipeInstructions": recipeInstructions,
        "ingredientIDs": ingredientIDs
    }
};
```

Then:

```
Recipes.findOneAndUpdate({ recipeID: id }, update, options, function(err) {
    if (err)
    {
        console.log("Unable to update");
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```